# Rails 3 multi nested resource form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-resources

I have got such routes:

```
  resources :projects do
    resources :chats
    resources :lists do
      resources :issues
    end
  end
```

Now I am trying to setup proper form to add issue to list, but I do not know how... Currently it looks like this:

Controller:

```
def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @list = List.new
    @issue = @list.issues.build


    @chats = @project.chats
    @lists = @project.lists.includes(:issues)


    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @project }
    end
  end
```

Form

```
form_for [@list, @issue], remote: true do |f|
```

And I get error like this:

```
undefined method `list_issues_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000003996f30>:0x000000038ad678>
```

How should I solve it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that is because it would need to be nested under the project. If you run `rake:routes` I imaging you have something like `projects/:id/lists/:id/issues/`?  You can see what the name of the route is next to that.  Otherwise you can add the `shallow` option to the lists route.

Comment: Yeap, my route looks exactly like you wrote.

Comment: Try doing `form_for [@project, @list, @issue]`

Comment: How should controller looks then? :-)

Comment: If you log out the params object I think you will have `params[:project_id]` `params[:list_id]`, and `params[:id]`.  You can use those to fetch the objects.  Or if you have the relations setup correctly you can then get them based on the id of the issue.

Comment: form_for with three models does not work. I used `shallow: true` instead. Thanks.